# Powershell, Stop-IISSite command fails for member of local Administrators

Tags: powershell, iis, windows-server

Trying to figure out why my local user that is member of Administrators can't use IIS powershell commands. Running the same command as Administrator works fine.

```
PS C:\Users\3dot> $user = "$env:COMPUTERNAME\$env:USERNAME"
PS C:\Users\3dot> $group = 'Administrators'
PS C:\Users\3dot> $isInGroup = (Get-LocalGroupMember $group).Name -contains $user
PS C:\Users\3dot> $isInGroup
True
PS C:\Users\3dot> Stop-IISSite Test -Confirm: $false
Stop-IISSite : Access is denied. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070005 (E_ACCESSDENIED))
At line:1 char:1
+ Stop-IISSite Test -Confirm: $false
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Stop-IISSite], UnauthorizedAccessException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.UnauthorizedAccessException,Microsoft.IIS.Powershell.Commands.StopIISSiteCommand
```

Comment: Testing if an user is in Administrators group does not necessarly means that you 've got the admin rights. Is this command `[Security.Principal.WindowsPrincipal]::new([Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity]::GetCurrent()).IsInRole([Security.Principal.WindowsBuiltInRole]::Administrator)` returns `$true` ? If it returns `$false`, UAC is enabled, so you need to run PowerShell with RunAs Administrator

Comment: Thanks. I am actually trying to do this through a SSL remote ps session between non domain PCs.
So I have to use Administrator credentials? That, or try to disable UAC somehow?

Comment: if your PowerShell is run elevated, you should'nt have to do so. But the text output sample you have provided, doesn't show up this is a remote session